# Fast way to store and retrieve pairs of numbers in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

I am implementing queued flood fill algorithm and need to store and retrieve pairs of numbers in `NSMutableArray`.

Basically, I am creating an array

```
m_queue = [NSMutableArray array];
```

then at some time I populate the array

```
[m_queue addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(x + 1, y)]];
```

then I retrieve data for the next iteration and remove the value at the beginning of the array

```
NSValue* value = [m_queue objectAtIndex:0];
[m_queue removeObjectAtIndex:0];
CGPoint nextPoint = [value CGPointValue];

[self queueFloodFill8:nextPoint.x y:nextPoint.y];
```

The question is: what can I do to avoid creating large number of `CGPoint` and `NSValue` objects?

I don't really need points, the algorithm uses pairs of integer values, so I think there might be a better way to store such pairs.

**UPDATE:**
I looked into implementing C-style solution like @mattjgalloway and @CRD suggested.

I've introduced

```
typedef struct lookup_point_struct
{
    int x;
    int y;
    struct lookup_point_struct* next;
} LookupPoint;
```

and have rewritten code to use linked list of such structs instead of `NSMutableArray` and `CGPoint`/`NSValue`.

All this made my code about 3 times faster. And memory consumption dropped significantly too.

Comment: why not a mutable array with even number of entries ?

Comment: @Vince this will bring twice as more `NSValue` allocations, array item allocations and removals. And the whole point is to speed up the whole process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There wouldn't really be a better Objective-C / Foundation way of doing it, apart from maybe creating your own class such as `NumberPair` or something which you put into the array rather than using `NSValue` and `CGPoint`. It might be slightly more memory efficient to do that and you could make `NumberPair` contain two integers rather than floats like you are concerned about. Something like:

```
@interface NumberPair : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) int x;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int y;
@end

@implementation NumberPair
@synthesize x, y;
@end

...

m_queue = [NSMutableArray array];

NumberPair *newPair = [[NumberPair alloc] init];
newPair.x = 1;
newPair.y = 2;
[m_queue addObject:newPair];

...

NumberPair *nextPoint = [m_queue objectAtIndex:0];
[m_queue removeObjectAtIndex:0];
[self queueFloodFill8:nextPoint.x y:nextPoint.y];
```

Other than that you could do a more C-like thing of having a `struct` containing two integers, create a dynamically allocated array to store the structs (you'd need to know the max size of the queue or keep reallocating). Something like:

```
typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
} NumberPair;

NumberPair *m_queue = (NumberPair*)malloc(sizeof(NumberPair) * QUEUE_SIZE);
// ... etc
```

Also, you might want to check out my [MJGStack](https://github.com/mattjgalloway/MJGFoundation/blob/master/Source/Model/MJGStack.h) class which wraps `NSMutableArray` to provide a stack like interface which you might be able to adjust slightly to do what you want rather than using `NSMutableArray` directly. Although that's not essential by any means.

Comment: Thank you for the hints. I've updated questions with information about what I've done.

Comment: Excellent! Nice solution in the end. A linked list like that is perfect for this.

Answer (score 1):

How large do you expect your `m_queue` array to get?

If the cost of the `NSMutableArray` and `NSValue` objects (`CGPoint` is a struct, no real cost there) is impacting your algorithm then consider using a C-style array of structs as a circular buffer together with two indexes for front/back of the queue. You can abstract this into a queue class (or an adt using functions to save on dynamic method call overhead if you need to).

If you need to deal with an unbounded queue you can `malloc` & `realloc` the array with your queue class/adt as needed (which is essentially what `NSMutableArray` does behind the scenes but with more overhead for its generality).

Comment: checked the code and for the image I am testing `m_queue` gets 800-2000 entries.

Comment: @Bobrovsky - You should probably benchmark the C-style method that @CRD and I have pointed out against your `CGPoint` method and also against the custom class method that I pointed out in my answer I would suggest.

Comment: @CRD Thank you, I've implemented something like you suggested (see update). I wish I could accept two answers as the answer :-)